# Ran the command sudo visudo and now I'm getting some errors

Tags: ubuntu

Ran `sudo visudo` and made some changes. After that, I'm getting the below error

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-113:~$ sudo su -
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 28 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 28
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

So I ran the command `pkexec nano /etc/sudoers`

But it shows

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-38-114:~$ pkexec nano /etc/sudoers
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/bin/nano' as the super user
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  Ubuntu (ubuntu)
 2.  Vishnu V R,,, (vishnu)
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 1
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing the command as another user: Not authorized
Provided the correct username and password for both users, but its not authenticating.
```

Comment: You may need to mount this disk from a live-boot usb of Ubuntu so that you can edit the /etc/sudoers freely.

Comment: Note that "how do I use/configure/repair my UNIX system?" questions are more on-topic at [unix.se] than here. Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing software_.

Comment: That said, the whole point of `visudo` is to ensure that the new file is valid before saving it. If you've found a way to make it save an invalid file, that's a bug, and you might consider reporting it upstream.

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). Please ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Comment: Also, please post an actual question. This is just a description of a problem. Do you need help repairing it, or figuring out what caused the problem, or reporting the problem to the developers, etc?